# I am not able to send the mail from my android application built for kindle fire?

Tags: java, android

Its showing dialog saying that there ia application that supports t

Answer (score 1):

Kindle fire is no official android device. It has no email client preinstalled (afaik) so without the user having installed an email client by itself, you will not be able to send an email. This message is correct in this case.

Comment: but its having email app installed.

Comment: Than this email app does not react on the intent you send.

Comment: ya...you are right, what else can be done?